# Zope buildout for development environment

Tags: zope, buildout

Is it possible to have Zope2 buildout unpack python files into their normal directories like how standard python modules do, and not under separate .egg directories? It makes looking for files easier when debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'regular' setup doesn't support namespaced packages very well, where multiple eggs share a top-level name (such as `plone.app` and `zope`, etc.)

Use the [`collective.recipe.omelette` buildout recipe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.omelette) to build a 'regular' setup, it uses symlinks to give you a searchable structure of all eggs used.

```
[buildout]
parts =
    omelette
    ...

[omelette]
recipe = collective.recipe.omelette
eggs = ${instance:eggs}
```

You'll find the result in `parts/omelette`. Note that this structure uses symlinks, so if you use tools like `find` or `ack` make sure to configure them to follow symlinks (e.g. `find parts/omelette -L` and `ack --follow`).

The omelette directory structure is *not* used by Python itself, it is purely intended for presenting a coherent library structure from all eggs used in your buildout.

Note that for Windows, you need to install the [junction utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) as well for the recipe to work.

Comment: @ChuiTey: The documentation states: *Using omelette on Windows requires the [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) utility to make links. Junction.exe must be present in your PATH when you run omelette.* So, yes, it works on Windows, with an add-on from MS. Updated my answer to include that information.